# Full text search in PostgreSQL using prisma is not working

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I am working on a nestJS project which use Prisma & PostgreSQL,
I am using fulltextsearch,
here is my schema

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["fullTextSearch"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id              String            @id @default(uuid())
  phoneNumber     String            @unique
}
```

here are some demo data

```
{
      "id": "a6affa5b-a819-4637-9e9f-f788a02e4594"
      "phoneNumber": "+911234567891"
},
{
      "id": "39443bb5-bbb5-43c8-b165-135fe24d3e82"
      "phoneNumber": "+919876543211"
},
{
      "id": "4bb631af-f437-4816-8f35-d356a174011f"
      "phoneNumber": "+915678912345"
},
```

when I use prisma search query I doesn't work properly,
like when I search

```
prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
          id: {
             search: "4bb631af"
          }
        }
      });
```

I get result but when I search this

```
prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
          id: {
             search: "f437-4816"
          }
        }
      });
```

I don't get any results

also

when I search

```
prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
          phoneNumber: {
             search: "+911234567891"
          }
        }
      });
```

I get results
but when I search

```
prisma.user.findMany({
        where: {
          phoneNumber: {
             search: "911234567891" // or  search: "567891"
          }
        }
      });
```

I don't get any results

Is there anything I should change in the schema or in the query ?

Comment: Does this resource about [Prismas filter operations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting) help?

Comment: @Palladium02 I have read the docs, I don't want to use ```contains``` or ```startsWith``` or ```endWith``` for some reason, also as they are showing in the docs the ```search``` options should work

Comment: recommend opening a github issue if one doesn't already exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full text search is not what you think. It is a feature to search *whole words* in *natural language* documents. It won't help you finding substrings or strings with special characters in them, and it is not very useful for numbers.

You should use substring search with

```
... LIKE '%567891%'
```

This can be sped up by using the pattern matching index support from the `pg_trgm` extension.

Comment: Sure but the [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/full-text-search) says it implement necessary text search to implement a contains filter. Looks like a documentation issue / missing feature

Comment: Yes, you are right, full text search should be performed on text based fields,